# Loss function of text generation in NLP

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language

I have a small project in my mind and thinking to implement, to generate regular expressions from natural language. I found the following issue when reading researches and I had an idea in my mind and found other researchers outlining the same problem.

Let's say my input is: 'Items with a numeral preceding a letter or small letter.'
It matches the regular expression: ([0-9]).*(([A-Za-z])&([a-z])).*
I know that the same input can have different correct outputs. But the sole idea here any small change in the output my model predicts such as: ([1-9]).*(([A-Za-z])&([a-z])).* with changing the '0' into a '1' will make it an incorrect prediction and it will be penalized harder than it should be. A way to tackle it is by counting how many sub-patterns it matches.

I am thinking for the sake of easiness and understanding it to use the Edit Distance metric. Let's say after training first sample the edit distance = 3. How shall the model be penalized ?
The model should be a seq2seq model, let's say an encoder-decoder LSTM. The decoder would output a pattern and get the loss function of it, and then ? Is that enough or there is something that should be considered ?

Comment: Figuring out a successful way to generate regex patterns from basic textual descriptions would be worthy of publication at top research venues. You’re asking a bit much of Cross Validated to figure out the particularities.

Comment: I agree with you completely. I was very careful to ask this question so I do not as 'much' from this community to help me out rather than helping me to understand if I am making sense in bigger picture or there is an essential component that I am missing. I did not want a specific guide for this kind of problem.